# iOS swift: Should I embed CMTimingInfo in Elementary Stream (to be sent over the network) along with H264 parameters and CMBlockBuffer?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, h.264, cmtime

I used the following stackoverflow posts to [extract h264 parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396622/extracting-h264-from-cmblockbuffer) , so I can send an elementary stream over the network and the receiving application will [reconstruct CMSampleBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525000/how-to-use-videotoolbox-to-decompress-h-264-video-stream/29525001#29525001).  However, no video image was displayed on AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer.

I took a step back and extracted the NAL units and reconstructed the CMSampleBuffer internally in the device. Then I discovered that I need to create a CMTimingInfo object and include it as one of the arguments for the method CMSampleBufferCreate. Then when I queued the newly created CMSampleBuffer to an AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer, the video image is displayed.

So I think I should integrate the CMTimingInfo in the elementary stream and sent that over the network. However, I have watched WWDC 2014 - Session 513 and they said nothing about including CMTimingInfo into the elementary stream.

Thank you in advance for responding to my question.

Comment: I'm in the exact same boat right now. Did you ever figure it out?